# How do you use bind_params for a timestamp data?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, timestamp

I am trying to get data on a database between two timestamps and I have seen many posts that use the BETWEEN. But I can't get past the error that is related to my bindparams that's why I can't test the codes that I saw on another post.

About the first part of my code, I just thought that the value on $date1 and $date2 is a string and I thought that maybe I need it to be converted to a MySQL timestamp format so I used the following code.

How do I use bindparams on a timestamp based on my code?

I tried the following code but I keep getting an error on POSTMAN. 
such as Number of variables doesn't match the number of parameters

This is the sample value for date1 and date 2 that I am using on Postman for testing

```
       $date1 is  2019-12-13 00:00:00
       $date2 is  2019-12-15 00:00:00
```

DbOperation.php

```
    //view cart product sales in cartData via date
    public function viewCartDatabyDate($date1, $date2){
        $timestamp1 = strtotime($date1);
        $timestamp2 = strtotime($date2);
        $newDate1=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp1);
        $newDate2=date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp2);

        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart_data WHERE created BETWEEN '$newDate1' AND '$newDate2' ORDER BY created");
        //$stmt->bind_param("s", $newDate1);
        //$stmt->bind_param("s", $newDate2);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $created);
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $cartdata[]=$data;
        }
        return $cartdata;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use placeholders. Question marks in SQL mean that this is the place where the variable is attached.

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart_data WHERE created BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY created");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $newDate1, $newDate2);
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$certdata = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```